# How can I make the criterias Work in Type Script

Tags: typescript, if-statement

I wonder how or if its possible to make these if and else criterias work? I dont know why this doesn't.
Thanks for your Help

```
if (element > 9) {
    Array.from(counter).forEach((element: HTMLElement, index) => {
            console.log(index, element);
            element.innerText = (index + 1).toString();
        });
}else (element <== 9) {
    Array.from(counter).forEach((element: HTMLElement, index) => {
                console.log(index, element);
                element.innerText = 0 + (index + 1).toString();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no operator `<==` in TypeScript. You should use `<=` instead or if you want strict type checking, cast `element` to integer before.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply, but this isn't quite it. I found the mistake. I shouldn't have to :"element<== 9" for example, because "element" is a HTML ELement. So the final Code Lokks like this : if (index > 9) {}else(index <= 9){} ! But thanks for your SUPER fast reply doe:).